# Excel VBA Time and Date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to alter this code so that it will work for what I need. I want to basically say that if today is Friday and the time is 4:00PM or greater, then the new time is Monday 7:00AM. Here is what I have but I cannot figure out the TIME part of it.

```
modDropOff = Now
LHour = Hour("4:00:00 PM")
LNewHour = Hour("07:00:00 AM")

If Weekday(Date) = vbFriday And Now() >= LHour Then
modDropOff = Date + 3 <<< + LNewHour
End If
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or it is just not passing the if.

Comment: No errors, the new TIME is not correct. I don't know how to do "Date + 3 and then add a new time instead of the current time.

Comment: I think I have searched a hundred examples but cannot find where to add to a date but always make the time static.

Comment: Try format(now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") for your time.

Comment: And make your LHour the same format on you should be able to do the compare.

Comment: You may also want to look at the TimeValue() function.

Comment: Times are fractions: Date+3 + LNewHour/86400

Comment: Thanks all for your time and help. Dealing with date & time modifications always seems so difficult as there seems to be a thousand ways to do one small thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit long-winded, but seems to work:

```
If Weekday(modDropOff) = 6 And Hour(modDropOff) >= 16 Then
    modDropOff = DateSerial(Year(modDropOff), Month(modDropOff), Day(modDropOff)) + 3 + TimeSerial(7, 0, 0)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to edit dates:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub checkDate()

    Dim modDropOff As Date

    If Weekday(Now) = 2 And Hour(Now) >= 16 Then

        modDropOff = (Date + 3) + TimeValue("07:00:00 AM")

    Else

        modDropOff = Now

    End If

    MsgBox Format(modDropOff, "ddd mmm dd, yyyy - hh:mm:ss AMPM")

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub editDate()
    Dim modDropOff As Date
    If Weekday(Now) = 2 And Hour(Now) >= 16 Then
        modDropOff = DateAdd("d", 3, Now)
        modDropOff = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now) + 3) + TimeSerial(7, 0, 0)
    Else
        modDropOff = Time
    End If
    MsgBox Format(xDate, "ddd mmm dd, yyyy - hh:mm:ss AMPM")
End Sub
```

.

Other VBA Date and Time functions

- Date - current system Date (Date part only)
- Now - current system Date and Time
- Year, Month, MonthName, WeekDay, WeekdayName, Day
- Hour, Minute, Second
- IsDate, CDate, DateSerial, DateValue, DateAdd, DateDiff, DatePart
- Time, TimeSerial, TimeValue
- FormatDateTime, Timer